# How do I filter out expressions from a line of text using Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I want to remove words that do not belong to a pre-defined list. For example, if my list is:

```
ANIMAL
BIRD
CARNIVORE
HERBIVORE
MAMMAL
OMNIVORE
```

My input is like this:

```
(ANIMAL (CARNIVORE (BIRD Peacock)) (HERBIVORE (MAMMAL Goat)))
```

I want my output to be:

```
(ANIMAL (CARNIVORE (BIRD )) (HERBIVORE (MAMMAL )))
```

I tried this:

```
current_split = re.split("\W", test)
    for thing in current_split:
        if thing in parse_symbols:
            print thing
```

But this removes the parentheses, and I get this:

```
ANIMAL
CARNIVORE
BIRD
HERBIVORE
MAMMAL
```

Also, because of the `for` loop, newlines are getting introduced, which I don't want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your input always going to have parentheses you want to keep? So the only things that need removing are extra alphabetic strings?

Comment: You want to add a "," after print and add a newline one level above

Comment: @mattjegan Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the foolproof solution: Use `re.sub` with a function. First get a `set` of the allowed words:

```
allowed = set("""
    ANIMAL
    BIRD
    CARNIVORE
    HERBIVORE
    MAMMAL
    OMNIVORE
""".split())
```

or use

```
allowed = {'ANIMAL', 'BIRD', #... and so forth
```

Then `re.sub` with a regex for each word `\w+`, then check if they're in the `ok` - if yes, then return that word, otherwise return an empty string:

```
def replacement(match):
    word = match.group(0)
    if word in allowed:
        return word
    return ''

result = re.sub(r'[\w-]+', replacement, user_input)
print(result)
```

prints

```
(ANIMAL (CARNIVORE (BIRD )) (HERBIVORE (MAMMAL )))
```

This will consider only entire words and entire words only, unlike the various `.replace` solutions provided here. It will only retain a word if the entire word is in the set of allowed words. It will never remove a part of a full word. It will work with whatever the separators and operators would be.

If you want to remove any excess space before the right parenthesis, use another substitution:

```
re.sub(r'\s+\)', '', result)
```

which for the above result will produce

```
(ANIMAL (CARNIVORE (BIRD) (HERBIVORE (MAMMAL))
```

Comment: should not you use `allowed` instead of `ok` in your `replacement` function?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest true thanks. That's the problem with coding in fragments and then rewriting variable names

Comment: @AnttiHaapala This works, but for a case like (ANIMAL (CARNIVORE (BIRD jay-bird))) the hyphen is being retained. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @user110327 by using a character class that includes any word character *or* the `-`. i.e. `[\w-]+`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I cannot follow you. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @user110327 I've fixed the code above to handle the case

Answer (score 2):

The solution using [***re.finditer()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) function:

```
import re

animals = ['ANIMAL', 'BIRD', 'CARNIVORE', 'HERBIVORE', 'MAMMAL', 'OMNIVORE']
user_input = '(ANIMAL (CARNIVORE (BIRD Peacock)) (HERBIVORE (MAMMAL Goat)))'

for m in re.finditer(r'[\w-]+', user_input):
    if m.group() not in animals:
        user_input = user_input.replace(m.group(), '')

print(user_input)
```

The output:

```
(ANIMAL (CARNIVORE (BIRD )) (HERBIVORE (MAMMAL )))
```

Comment: No, you could remove a *prefix* of any word.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, what do you mean with *prefix*? unclear what you are writing

Comment: your code finds every word not in the `user_input` and replaces with `''` everywhere, even if they were a part of another word.

Answer (score 0):

Use re sub:

```
bird = re.compiler'(BIRD) (\w*?)\)'
mammal = re.compile(r'(MAMMAL) (\w*?)\)')

nobirds  = re.sub(bird, r'\1', input) #keeps only the first group
nomammals = re.sub(mammal, r'\1', input)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to process strings similar to the one you provided with parentheses, You can just `split` the line into words, `strip` them of parentheses, and then check if they are allowed or not:

```
allowed = ['ANIMAL', 'BIRD', 'CARNIVORE', 'HERBIVORE', 'MAMMAL', 'OMNIVORE']
line = '(ANIMAL (CARNIVORE (BIRD Peacock)) (HERBIVORE (MAMMAL Goat)))'
words = [word.strip('()') for word in line.split()]
not_allowed = [word for word in words if word not in allowed]
```

Now that we found all the words we want to remove, we just remove them, like this:

```
newline = line
for word in not_allowed:
    newline = newline.replace(word, '')
```

The only thing wrong with `newline` now is those annoying spaces before the parentheses where we removed words, but that's easy:

```
newline = newline.replace(' )', ')')
```

Your newline now should output `'(ANIMAL (CARNIVORE (BIRD)) (HERBIVORE (MAMMAL)))'`

Also, as you can see I did not print each and every word during this session, which is why I get one single line `newline` that I can now print instead of multiple new lines on each `print` command